# How to execute hql files with multiple SQL queries per single file?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have hql file which have a lot of hive queries and I would like to execute the whole file using Spark SQL.

This is what I have tried.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

Usually to execute individual queries we do it this way:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from table")
```

However, when we have hql file with hundreds of queries, I use to do like this.

```
import scala.io.Source 

val filename = "/path/to/file/filename.hql"
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
    sqlContext.sql(line)
}
```

However, I get an error saying:

```
NoViableAltException
```

This is the top of the file.

```
DROP TABLE dat_app_12.12_app_htf;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dat_app_12.12_app_htf(stc string,
  ftg string,
  product_type string,
  prod_number string,
  prod_ident_number string,
  prod_family string,
  frst_reg_date date, gth_name string,
  address string,
  tel string,
  maker_name string) ROW format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
stored AS inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'file_location';
```

When the queries are multi-line queries like the above one, it doesn't work.
However, when I format the queries and put all the lines into one line, it works.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dat_app_12.12_app_htf(stc string, ftg string, product_type string, prod_number string, prod_ident_number string, prod_family string, frst_reg_date date, gth_name string, address string, tel string, maker_name string) ROW format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' stored AS inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat' LOCATION 'file_location';
```

But I have thousands of lines like this. What is the proper way to do it.

Can anyone help in getting this solved.

Comment: The proper way to do is to let Hive do it for you. `beeline -f query.sql`

Comment: Can you write the whole query. Where do we execute this query? In hive? Spark-sql? or in the bash?

Comment: Yes, you have to invoke it from bash. You can either use `hive -f` or `beeline -f`

Comment: This is how I am executing it in the bash:    
    spark-sql –master yarn-client –conf spark.ui.port=port -i /hadoop/sbscript/hql_for_dml.hql

But still it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** I don't think it's possible.

Spark SQL uses [AstBuilder](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/AstBuilder.scala) as the ANTLR-based SQL parser and accepts a single SQL statement at a time (see [SqlBase.g4](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4) for the full coverage of all supported SQL queries).

With that said, the only way to do it is to parse the multi-query input file yourself *before* calling Spark SQL's `sqlContext.sql` (or `spark.sql` as of Spark 2.0).

You could rely on empty lines as separators perhaps, but that depends on how input files are structured (and they could easily use semicolon instead).

---

In your particular case I've noticed that the end markers are actually semicolons.

```
// one query that ends with semicolon
DROP TABLE dat_app_12.12_app_htf;

// another query that also ends with semicolon
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dat_app_12.12_app_htf(stc string,
  ftg string,
  product_type string,
  prod_number string,
  prod_ident_number string,
  prod_family string,
  frst_reg_date date, gth_name string,
  address string,
  tel string,
  maker_name string) ROW format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
stored AS inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'file_location';
```

If that's consistent, you could parse the file line by line (as you do with `for` expression) and read until `;` is found. Multiple-line SQL queries are fine for Spark SQL and so you should have your solution.

---

I had a similar use case in a project and simply gave up trying to parse all the possible ways people write SQLs before I could hand it over to Spark.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Did you try with this command

```
spark-sql –master yarn-client –conf spark.ui.port=port -i /hadoop/sbscript/hql_for_dml.hql
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works but it seems we can't run hql file as it is and the hive queries need to be formatted in order for it to be executed. For example if I a multi-line query, it does not work, but when I put all the arguments into a one line, it works.

Comment: If your multi-line query working fine individually than it should also work after putting inside .hql file, unless it has something broken, use any sql for-matter instead of manually formatting.